# Cannot create EF code first mapping class using generics

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have several entites that are identical except for the class name that each are mapped to a corresponding identical table.  The mapping for each table is similar to the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(x =>
{
  x.MapInheritedProperties();
  x.ToTable("Foo");
})
```

This approach works, but is repetitive.

I created this class hoping to get rid of the reposition.  it is simplified here for brevity.

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public Generic(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string tableName)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable(tableName);
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler error that I do not understand:

```
The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntityType' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Entity<TEntityType>()'
```

- Like many .Net coders I use generics a lot but do not write them often.
- I have use EF for a while, but I am pretty new to Code First
- I did a lot of searching on and off of SO with no luck.
- What am I doing wrong?  What do I not understand?

Thanks in advance,
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add generic parameter constraint `where T : class`:

```
public class Generic<T>
   where T : class
{
    public Generic(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string tableName)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable(tableName);
        });
    }
}
```

Same constraint exist on `DbModelBuilder.Entity<T>` method, that's why you need same constraint in your generic class.

Answer (score 3):

The error states that your generic lacks a `class` constraint. [Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) about "Constraints on Type Parameters".

So `Generic<T>` should be declared as

```
public class Generic<T> where T: class
{
    public Generic(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string tableName)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable(tableName);
        });
    }
}
```

But I would suggest using [EntityTypeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). This class will allow you to separate entity mappings from context and implement a kind of inheritance you wanted.

For example:

```
public abstract class EntityConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    protected EntityConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable(typeof(T).Name);

        // All primary keys are named as <EntityName>Id
        Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName(typeof(T).Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

This class states that all entities will have a mapping to table which name is equal to name of the type and every table has an primary key column with name `<TableName>Id`.

Then mapping configuration for entity `Foo` could be declared as following:

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());
        // add you mapping logic here
    }
}
```

Then configuration should be registered in DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and the extra information.  I had already marked the earlier response as the answer.  But, I wanted you to know that I appreciated the additional info.  I always appreciate learning something new.

Answer (score 0):

EF provides a class that allows you to do this:

```
class SomeEntityMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<SomeEntity>
{
    public SomeEntityMapping()
    {
        ToTable("My_Entity");
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        //...
    }
}
```

Then, in your DbContext, override OnModelCreating and add the Mappings to the configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
   builder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityConfiguration());
}
```